# Is it okay for me to let everyone know about my certificate?

Tags: android, code-signing

Someone I know asked me to publish my certificate so that, in the future if ever I developed an app that required authenticity, they can verify the APK did come from me.

1. Is that true? Can people verify the APK using the certificate?
2. Is it secure? Can other people use my certificate to sign another APK?

The certificate looks like this (I won't use this, so feel free to scrutinize it):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to publish any key unless you have some clients that they need to be sure this apk is yours. In that case you just give them your `public key` . Note: never publish your private key , with your private key someone can edit your apk and published.

public key :

> A public-key certificate, also known as a digital certificate or an identity certificate, contains the public key of a public/private key pair, as well as some other metadata identifying the owner of the key (for example, name and location). The owner of the certificate holds the corresponding private key.
>
> When you sign an APK, the signing tool attaches the public-key certificate to the APK. The public-key certificate serves as as a "fingerprint" that uniquely associates the APK to you and your corresponding private key. This helps Android ensure that any future updates to your APK are authentic and come from the original author.

Private key:

> A keystore is a binary file that contains one or more private keys. When you sign an APK for release using Android Studio, you can choose to generate a new keystore and private key or use a keystore and private key you already have. You should choose a strong password for your keystore, and a separate strong password for each private key stored in the keystore. You must keep your keystore in a safe and secure place.
>
> Maintaining the security of your private key is of critical importance, both to you and to the user. If you allow someone to use your key, or if you leave your keystore and passwords in an unsecured location such that a third-party could find and use them, your authoring identity and the trust of the user are compromised.

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't share any certificates or keys with anyone.
Illegal usage of your keys by other people results in playstore account removal by google.
And you can't use your same PC again to compile Android apps for publishing (even if you manage to get another account).
Also it helps other people to crack or republish your application